# How can I prevent my web crawler from slowing down over time?

Tags: c#, .net, web, web-crawler

I made a web crawler in C#. It starts from one URL, finds all URLs in that URL and then visits all other URLs, and so on...

I add the URLs to a string array with a pre-defined size and a Dictionary so I can check if the URL has already been crawled (I use Dictionary's ContainsKey() method because it's faster than a linear array search).

It is very fast when it starts working, but over time it gets painfully slow. The reason for this is that the Dictionary's Contains() method takes a lot of time when the Dictionary is very big (100K+ URLs, for example), and that means my web crawler is slowing down quickly over time.

What can I do about this? I have to check if a URL has been added already, and a Dictionary lookup is the fastest way, but even this way gets slow after the Dictionary gets large enough.

Comment: why not have a dictionary per domain? and whenever you are done with a given domain save the result to a file, because what the chance of duplicates in 2 different domains?

Comment: I don't crawl inside of domains, I only crawl the domains themselves from other websites (for example, I'll not crawl http://youtube.com/watch?v=3dnf33, I'll only crawl http://youtube.com). Should I still make a dictionary per domain?

Comment: you can do the following, whenever 5000 or so unique websites are found save them to a text file, in the end loop the resulted files put them into a  list and call Distinct() and save...

Comment: OK, sounds like a nice idea, I'll try it. Thank you very much!

Comment: How long are we talking for a `ContainsKey()` lookup? I wouldn't have thought a lookup would take that long - since Dictionaries are HashTables, they generally can do a `ContainsKey()` in O(1) time. What I'd be more concerned about would be the time it takes to add to the Dictionary, and general memory requirements to hold such a large Dictionary. Is your web crawler multi-threaded?